# Filter data using exposed filter using country in drupal 7?

Tags: views

I want to filter all views data through IP address (or country) on the front page.

How can I work with exposed filter module? Is there any other method to filter data using selection box (Countries)?

Answer (score 1):

Entities are opened for views to show results. Fields are attached to entities, and with views you can either show the fields or can filter your results with the fields. So, assuming you are trying to make a view of any entity (node,user etc.), you can use the [Address field](https://drupal.org/project/addressfield) or the [Countries](https://drupal.org/project/countries) module and add the field provided by any of the module to entity you are listing though views.

After adding the field to the entity, the same field will be available in views to be showed or used as exposed filters.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of these modules (quotes included are from their project pages):

- [Smart IP](https://www.drupal.org/project/smart_ip):

  > ... identifies visitor's geographical location (longitude/latitude), country, region, city and postal code based on the IP address of the user. These information will be stored at session variable ($_SESSION) with array key 'smart_ip' and Drupal $user->data object with array key 'geoip_location' of the user but optionally it can be disabled (by role) at Smart IP admin page. Other modules can use the function smart_ip_get_location($ip_address) that returns an array containing the visitor's ISO 3166 2-character country code, longitude, latitude, region (FIPS), city and postal code. It provides a feature for you to perform your own IP lookup and admin spoofing of an arbitrary IP for testing purposes.
- [IP Geolocation Views & Maps](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc):

  > Despite what the name may suggest, IP Geolocation Views & Maps (IPGV&M) is first and foremost a mapping engine.
  >
  > The module makes it very easy to create Views-based mapping solutions using the map renderer of your choice (Google, OpenLayers or Leaflet) with any location storage module of your choice, e.g. Get Locations, Geofield, Geolocation Field or Location.
  >
  > This allows you to bring together modules and feature sets that without IPGV&M you would not be able to combine.
- [Location](https://www.drupal.org/project/location):

  > ... allows real-world geographic locations to be associated with Drupal nodes, including people, places, and other content. The Location module allows admins to collect addresses, geocode them (translate addresses to lattitude/longitude), and associate locations with Drupal nodes and users. Location data is automatically used to generate GeoRSS within your existing RSS feeds.